# How to add a json object in to a json array using scala play?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

In my scala code i have a json object consisting email data

```
val messages = inboxEmail.getMessages();
var jsonArray = new JsArray
for(inboxMessage <- messages)
{
    ...
    ...
    val emailJson = Json.obj("fromAddress" -> fromAddressJsonList, "toAddress" -> toAddressJsonList, "ccAddress" -> ccAddressJsonList, "bccAddress" -> bccAddressJsonList, "subject" -> emailMessage.getSubject().toString(), "message" -> Json.toJson(emailMessageBody))
```

I need to add emailJson to the jsonArray during each loop

i tried

```
jsonArray.+:(emailJson)
```

and

```
jsonArray.append(emailJson)
```

but getting empty array

What should i use here to add jsonObject into the json array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember that `JsArray` is immutable, so writing

```
jsonArray.+:(emailJson)
```

will not modify `jsonArray`, it will just create a new json array with `emailJson` appended at the end.

Instead you would need to write something like:

```
val newArray = jsonArray +: emailJson
```

and use `newArray` instead of `jsonArray` afterwards.

In your case, you said you need to add an element "at each loop iteration". When using a functional language like Scala, you should probably try to think more in terms of "mapping over collections" rather than "iterating in a loop". For example you could write:

```
val values = messages map {inboxMessage =>
    ...
    ...
    Json.obj("fromAddress" -> fromAddressJsonList, "toAddress" -> toAddressJsonList, "ccAddress" -> ccAddressJsonList, "bccAddress" -> bccAddressJsonList, "subject" -> emailMessage.getSubject().toString(), "message" -> Json.toJson(emailMessageBody))
}
val newArray = objects ++ JsArray(values)
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer